Installing unixODBC in a Lambda function
I am using docker to install and package pyodbc with unixODBC as a layer for a Lambda function, and in the docker container I can run odbcinst -q -d and I get: [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
However, when I run the same command in my Lambda function using print(subprocess.run(['odbcinst', '-q', '-d'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)) I instead get odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with Unable to find component name.
I believe this is happening from the environment variable. I don't have one set in my dockerfile, so I set it in Lambdas to odbcinst.ini. In docker I run odbcinst -j -i /opt/etc/odbcinst.ini and I see
unixODBC 2.3.1 DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
But again, in Lambas, I see:
unixODBC 2.3.1 DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/sbx_user1051/.odbc.ini
I have tried changing the ODBCINSTINI environment variable to /opt/etc/odbcinst.ini, but when I do that, the previous command then says DRIVERS is /etc//opt/etc/odbcinst.ini. You see how it just seems to append /etc/ to whatever the evn variable is? I'm not sure what to do here.
